# php Проверка соответствует ли текст шаблону

Tags: php

Есть такие строки:

```
"1212 "
"2342 "
"2345 ыаоы 4342 2"
" 43 авп"
" 4434 "
```

Мне надо проверять состоит ли строка точно по шаблону `([0-9]+ ){1}`. 
На первый взгляд легко кажется, но как-то не смог нормально работающую функцию написать. Пробовал через `preg_match()` но не получилось. Например, такую `3434 53` строку тоже считает правильной.

Мне надо проверить, начинается ли текст именно из цифр и заканчивается ли с одним пробелом.

Comment: Используйте в регулярке обозначение начала строки `^` и ее конца `$`. `{1}` лишние буквы.

Comment: "^([0-9]+) $^" не сработал. Без ^ в конце вообще ошибку дает.

Comment: `preg_match('/^[0-9]+\s$/',$string)`

Answer (score 2):

Под ваше условие - "начинается ли текст именно из цифр и заканчивается ли с одним пробелом"

```
^[0-9].*\s$
```

Проверка в notepad++ http://prntscr.com/erwzm4

Для PHP

```
$subject='1212 ';
preg_match_all ('/^[0-9].*\s$/', $subject, $matches);
```

Live Demo - https://eval.in/767019

Comment: точно точно? а то как будто ошибка

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: как конвертировать это на php pattern?

Comment: Для PHP еще нужно указывать делимитер, обновил ответ

Comment: вас не смущает. что у вас `.*`  в середине пропускает вообще все в строку? а автору надо `число-пробел`

Comment: Я ж указал - "начинается ли текст именно из цифр и заканчивается ли с одним пробелом"